# Activiti designer installation issue

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, activiti

I am using Eclipse indigo(Indigo Service Release 1).

When am trying to install Activiti pluggin through http://activiti.org/designer/update.

It gives the following error.

Help me..Thanks in advance

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Activiti Eclipse BPMN 2.0 Designer 5.10.0 (org.activiti.designer.feature.feature.group 5.10.0)
  Software currently installed: SwitchYard Editor 0.5.0.v20120713-1659-H145-Final (org.switchyard.tools.editor.feature.feature.group 0.5.0.v20120713-1659-H145-Final)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Graphiti UI (Incubation) 0.8.2.v20120215-0845 (org.eclipse.graphiti.ui 0.8.2.v20120215-0845)
    Graphiti UI (Incubation) 0.8.0.v20110606-1453 (org.eclipse.graphiti.ui 0.8.0.v20110606-1453)
    Graphiti UI (Incubation) 0.8.1.v20110829-1438 (org.eclipse.graphiti.ui 0.8.1.v20110829-1438)
    Graphiti UI (Incubation) 0.9.1.v20120919-0732 (org.eclipse.graphiti.ui 0.9.1.v20120919-0732)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Activiti Eclipse BPMN 2.0 Designer 5.10.0 (org.activiti.designer.feature.feature.group 5.10.0)
    To: org.eclipse.graphiti.ui 0.9.1
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Graphiti (Incubation) 0.8.0.v20110607-1252 (org.eclipse.graphiti.feature.feature.group 0.8.0.v20110607-1252)
    To: org.eclipse.graphiti.ui [0.8.0.v20110606-1453]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Graphiti (Incubation) 0.8.1.v20110907-0857 (org.eclipse.graphiti.feature.feature.group 0.8.1.v20110907-0857)
    To: org.eclipse.graphiti.ui [0.8.1.v20110829-1438]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Graphiti (Incubation) 0.8.2.v20120215-0845 (org.eclipse.graphiti.feature.feature.group 0.8.2.v20120215-0845)
    To: org.eclipse.graphiti.ui [0.8.2.v20120215-0845]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: SwitchYard Editor 0.5.0.v20120713-1659-H145-Final (org.switchyard.tools.editor.feature.feature.group 0.5.0.v20120713-1659-H145-Final)
    To: org.eclipse.graphiti.feature.feature.group [0.8.0,0.9.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two Graphiti dependencies, or the designer is trying to add one of those:

Graphiti UI (Incubation) 0.8.1.v20110829-1438 
Graphiti UI (Incubation) 0.9.1.v20120919-0732

You only can have one of both, so you should remove one of them.